# Understanding Hom functions

Tags: functions, category-theory

I am very new to category theory. Started learning about this Hom sets/functions.
I read $\operatorname{Hom}(S,T)$ as set of all functions from $S$ to $T$ but somehow this is a overloaded definition where $\operatorname{Hom}(S,T)$ is a function if $T$ is a function. I don't get that.

More over how is $\operatorname{Hom}(S,f)(g) = f \circ g$?
How $f$ is injective if $\operatorname{Hom}(S,f)$ is injective?

I tried googling but it seems way too complicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\operatorname{Hom}(S,-)$ is more accurately a *functor* from some category (say, to simplify matters, Sets) to Sets. This means that it's both a "function" that takes a set and gives you back a set, and also a "function" that takes a morphism of sets (a function) and gives you back a morphism of sets. In this case, the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(S,-)$ takes a set $T$ and gives you back the set $\operatorname{Hom}(S,T)$ of functions between $S$ and $T$, and it takes a function $f:T\rightarrow U$ and gives you back a function $\operatorname{Hom}(S,f)=f\circ -:\operatorname{Hom}(S,T)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(S,U)$.

To answer a comment below, you can be more visual by drawing the following commutative triangle:

$$ \begin{array}{cccc}
& S & & \\
g& \downarrow & \searrow \\
& T & \xrightarrow{f} & U\\
\end{array} $$

Here the mapping $\operatorname{Hom}(S,f)$ takes as input the vertical arrow $g:S \to T$ and "pushes it forward" to the diagonal arrow to its right, which is just the composition $f \circ g$.

To answer your second question, $\operatorname{Hom}(S,f)$ being injective means that for any pair of mappings $g,g':S\rightarrow T$, we have that $f\circ g = f \circ g' \implies g = g'$. In other words, it means that $f$ is left-cancellative, which means exactly that $f$ is injective (in the category of sets).

Note that a dual construction gives you a functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,T)$, which is *contravariant*. This means that this functor reverses arrows: if you feed it a function $f:S\rightarrow U$, it gives you back a function $-\circ f:\operatorname{Hom}(U,T)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(S,T)$.

Comment: So how does haskell's Functor typeclass fits. It has an fmap. So that fits the definition of Hom(S,f) = Hom(S,T) -> Hom(S,U). But It doesnt define Hom(S,T) itself. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @vinothkr I know nothing about Haskell, but in mathematics Hom(S,T) is by definition the set of morphisms from S to T in the category you're working in.

Comment: What is that fmap and Functor typeclass?

Comment: Is it at all possible for someone to give a more visual explanation of Hom(S,f)? Having a hard time understanding.

Comment: @Micah See my edited second paragraph, does this help?

Comment: @AlexP. so nice of you to respond. So basically, Hom(S,T) involves 2 sets, Hom(S,f) involves 3. So is it safe to say that Hom(S,T) equals the result of Hom(S,f) if f is the identity function applied to T?

Comment: @Micah If $f:T \to T$ is the identity, then by definition $Hom(S,f)$ takes any $g:S \to T$ to itself; thus $Hom(S,f)$ is the *identity* map from $Hom(S,T)$ to itself. In fact this is one of the defining properties of a functor: it must preserve identities.

Comment: @AlexP. ok so my real issue here is that in Barr-Wells definition of functors comes after definition of Hom(S,-). I think i generally get it now from your comments though. Thanks so much!